# xlwings runpython() parameters - passing path of the script.py which is not in the same excel's directory

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-3.x, xlwings

I read the `xlwings` documentation about `runpython()` but the function is working only if the python script and the excel are in the same directory.

I would like to know if it's possible to give in argument the path of my python scrip into `the runpython` function like:

```
Sub python_test()
    runpython ("import P:\mission_1; mission_1.manipulation()")
End Sub
```

if my script `mission_1.py` is located in the `P:\` directory.

Comment: You can set the `PYTHONPATH` in the config, see the docs here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings You can achieve that via the global or folder config file or via the config sheet.

Comment: Hi Felix, first of all, thanks to have answer my post ! Sorry but where can I find those folder ? In the config module, I can't find the PYTHON PATH variable ? Of course, I already install xlwings addin. I'm using windows seven and excel 2007

Comment: You basically edit the global config file via Ribbon and the location is indicated here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-config-ribbon-config-file. Otherwise you need to put one manually into your folder (or use the config sheet).

Comment: Hi Felix, I just forgot to thank you :) I'm a new user on this website